# Trouble adding observers inside an actor

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change a value in an actor when the application enters the background. Normally, I'd do this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  self,
  selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground), // error 1
  name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, // error 2
  object: nil
)

@objc private func applicationDidEnterBackground() { // error 3
  foo = true
}
```

However, I can't do this because it gives me the errors:

1. Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'applicationDidEnterBackground()' that is not exposed to Objective-C
2. Main actor-isolated class property 'didEnterBackgroundNotification' can not be referenced on a non-isolated actor instance
3. Actor-isolated instance method 'applicationDidEnterBackground()' cannot be @objc

How can I do this within my actor? Or will I need to have a wrapper to my actor that observers `didEnterBackgroundNotification` and calls a method on my actor?

Comment: I'm using `MainActor` to register for notifications, which at least solves the issue with accessing `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification`.